# Create new one or create a new one

Tags: articles

I apologize for the simple question.

We have the text:

> We will close this ticket, please reopen it or create new one if anything will be unclear or if you will have more questions.

But in my opinion it should be `create a new one` instead of `create new one` after taking a look at [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/a-an-and-the) post also.

Am I right?
 Which one is grammatically correct?

Thank you for your interest and time.

Comment: Hi @AlanCarmack. Well, I didn't find that post after searching a while. But are you sure that the questions are the same?

Comment: Sometimes the question doesn't seem exactly the same as the suggested duplicate, but the answers will be the same. When someone suggests a duplicate, it's a good idea to read over the answers to the other question to see if they are helpful to you. If they aren't helpful, [edit] your question to explain how your question is different. Don't worry if your question gets put on hold before you've had a chance to clarify it - we can always reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the use of ***a*** you are creating a list of instructions:

create new ticket,
send letter,
cook meal

which (in my opinion) is a bit less polite.

Create ***a*** new one would be better suited here.